# Best way to partition 1 TB (Linux and Windows 7)

Tags: windows, linux, partitioning, lvm

Is there an intelligent way to partition 1 TB and be prepared for resizing/adding/deleting partitions?

I was thinking about [LVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_%28Linux%29), but as far as I remember, Windows 7 can't be installed on logical volume right?

For now my plan is:
- ~150 GB for Windows 7 and other stuff ([Visual Studio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio)..., maybe I'll split it 100/50 or something like that) - simple NTFS
- 850 GB => LVM - disk for Linux (Ubuntu) and other stuff virtual machines, etc.

I'm mostly interested in how and what tools should I use to get easy in maintain partitions for both systems.

Comment: Windows has something called Dyanmic Disk - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731274 which is similar to LVM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot install Windows on anything that does not have the ***active*** flag in the [MBR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record). Logical partitions cannot use this flag. You can, however, install it on a primary and then mirror the contents to a logical partition, but it is tedious and not worth the effort.

You could use [GParted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GParted), but I wouldn't suggest resizing partitions.

Tell me what is it you want to do exactly? The Windows partition and [NTFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS) storage shouldn't be resized. If you run out of space on the OS partition you could use symbolic links to move huge files and make it look like they are in the same place.

You could place the Linux OS partition last so that you can resize it using the available unpartitioned space.

Comment: Thx good idea with symbolic links. I just wanted to have flexible storage. If i run out of space on Windows partition or Linux's I just wanted to resize them fast and safely.

Comment: @Simon You could do this (using gparted): Make a primary partition and create an extended partition. Leave some unpartitioned space between the extended and primary. Say 50 GB or whatever you like. That way when you need to resize your primary part. you won't need to 'kill' the extended one. Do this on all your other partitions as weel. If you ever need to exapand just use that unpartitioned space adjacent. Much easier than resizing an already-made partition and moving it around.

Answer (score 0):

[Wubi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wubi_%28Ubuntu_installer%29) might be an option. Otherwise, [Ubuntu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29) handles the partition management much better in my experience, so just use the built-in tools to resize partitions from there.

Comment: I don't know how it could help. It's just virtual partition for linux inside windows. Main issue is: how to safely resize windows' partition. I know how to handle linux.

Answer (score 0):

[Acronis](http://www.acronis.com/) has a product called Disk Director that can handle hard disk partitioning and resizing for both Windows and Linux. I've used it for many years and found it quite useful. They also have an optional boot manager to handle booting into multiple OSs on the same disk.

Comment: Booting isn't problem. Recently I've resized partition for friend. Everything took 4 hours, so it's not what i want. But thx